# Reformatting a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reformatting

Sorry I am going crazy over this.

I have a 300K rows x 60 column data set that is

```
|country| variable  | 1960 | 1961 | .... |2017|
| US    | GDP       | 122  | 323  | .....| 838|
```

I want to convert it to.

```
Year  |country | Variable |
1960
1961
```

i.e. to put the variables in each column and have rows for years and countries.

I am sorry I hope this question makes sense. `t()` would not work because it also puts the countries in columns too.

Comment: Thank you. You marked it as duplicated. Do you by any chance have a link to post with the exact question please?

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful and worked perfectly. Thank you very much